# Trouble getting value from php and display on html

Tags: php, html

I have two files. One is tempTesting.php and another is using flot to graph the data displayed on project.html. But I cannot get the value from the tempTesting.php and display it on project.html.
When I run the project.html it gives me a syntax error on this line:

`var dat = <?php echo $return; ?>;`

tempTesting.php

```
<?php
$return="[123456789,22.55],[234567891,22.32]";
$maxtemp=-10;
$mintemp=50;
?>
```

project.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
    <head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
    <title>Flot For Temperature Project</title>  


        <script src="jquery.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script src="jquery.flot.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <!--[if IE]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.pack.js"></script><![endif]-->  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.time.js"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.symbol.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.colorhelpers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.canvas.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.crosshair.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fillbetween.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.image.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.navigate.js"></script>


        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  

        $(function () {
        var dat = <?php echo $return;?>;
        var options = {
          xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: "%h:%M %d.%m.%y", labelWidth: "10" },
          series: {
          lines: { show: true, fill: true, fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)" },
          points: { show: true, fill: false },
          shadowSize: 5,
          color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)"
        },
        grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
        yaxis: { min: <?php echo $mintemp-2;?> , max: <?php echo $maxtemp+2;?>, tickFormatter: function (v, axis) { return v.toFixed(axis.tickDecimals) +"°C" }},
        selection: { mode: "x", color: "rgba(125,0,0,0.6)" },
        legend: { show: true, position: "se", backgroundOpacity: 0.4, backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)", labelBoxBorderColor: "rgb(0,0,0)"},
      };
      var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),[ { data: dat, label: "Study Temp", color:"#333"} ], options);
      var overview = $.plot($("#overview"), [ { data: dat, label: "Min: °C, Max: °C", color: "#333"} ], {
        series: {
          color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",
          lines: { show: true, lineWidth: 1, fill: true, fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)" },
          shadowSize: 0
        },
          xaxis: { ticks: [], mode: "time" },
          yaxis: { ticks: [], min: 0, autoscaleMargin: 0.1 },
          selection: { mode: "x", color: "rgba(125,0,0,0.6)" },
          legend: { show: true, position: "se", backgroundOpacity: 1, backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)", labelBoxBorderColor: "rgb(0,0,0)" }});
        $("#placeholder").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
          plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [dat],
          $.extend(true, {}, options, {
          xaxis: { min: ranges.xaxis.from, max: ranges.xaxis.to }
        }));
        overview.setSelection(ranges, true);
      });
      $("#overview").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
        plot.setSelection(ranges);
      });
      var humanTime;
      var jstime;
      function showTimes(t) {
        var datum = new Date(parseFloat(t));
        humanTime = datum.toUTCString();
      }
      function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
        $('' + contents + '').css( {
          position: 'absolute',
          display: 'none',
          top: y + 25,
          left: x + 0,
          border: '2px solid #777',
          padding: '2px',
          'font-family': 'Arial',
          'font-size:': '1.2em',
          'font-weight': 'bold',
          'background-color': '#ddd',
          opacity: 0.80
        }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
      }
      var previousPoint = null;
      $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
        $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
        $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));
        if (item) {
          if (previousPoint != item.datapoint) {
            previousPoint = item.datapoint;
            $("#tooltip").remove();
            var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(0),
            y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);
            showTimes(x);
            showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
            y + "°C (at " + humanTime + "+1000)");
          }
        }
        else {
          $("#tooltip").remove();
          previousPoint = null;
        }
      });
    });
        </script>  
        </head >

            <body>  
        <?php
    include('tempTesting.php');

    ?>
        <div id="placeholder" style="height:300px;width=100px;"></div>
        <div id="overview"></div>



        <p>Flot Temperature realtime update. Below here is the Information</p>  

        </body>  
        </html>
```

Comment: Which error are you seeing exactly? This is also much too much code to scan.

Comment: @feeela  var dat = <?php echo $return;?>;

Comment: should be `var dat = "<?php echo $return; ?>";`

Comment: @evuez it kind of working...

Comment: See my answer for a short explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `var dat = "<?php echo $return; ?>";` instead.

Without quotes, if `$return` contains a string, javascript will interpret it as a variable, which is I think not the desired result.

Also, I you didn't set you server configuration to execute PHP in HTML files, this won't work since your file has a '.html' extension. Just rename your file to 'project.php' and it should be OK.

Comment: it soloved the error but is doesn't give me the value

Comment: On the page, because I set alert inside the code. It give me (new String("[<?php echo $return; ?>]")) and the graph only show me one line

Comment: on my mac, when I changed it to php, i could not use firefox to open it. it only allows me to open it as code file.

Comment: Did you ever work with PHP? If not, I suggest you to follow a simple PHP tutorial like this one http://us3.php.net/tut.php. Just so you know, you will have to run a local web server to make it work (look for mamp on google if you want to get started quickly)

Comment: right .  I forgot that . it should run on server .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call PHP functions within a Javascript script. When the page loads, PHP is rendered first, followed by CSS and Javascript. So the line `var dat = <?php echo $return;?>;` wouldn't run properly.

Instead, you can use an Ajax request. [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19814557/1013029).

EDIT: Understood the question wrong. You cannot use PHP functions within a Javascript function dynamically. However, accessing just an echo command works.

Comment: Of course that's possible (calling PHP functions in JS is not, of course). `<?php echo $return ?>` gets rendered as echoing any other variable elsewhere.

Comment: PHP gets executed on the server side, while javascript is executed on the client side. So when the Javascript gets run, it is unable to access the php echo code.

Comment: Sorry to say, but you're wrong. The javascript part is a part of the html being rendered by PHP. It can contain any value it wishes. If I would be able to do `echo "<div>hello</div>";` I would surely be able to do `echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello');</script>'` .. makes no difference ..

Comment: Hmm... Guess I saw it wrong. I was thinking if the PHP was doing some dynamic computation when the Javascript code is called, then that wouldn't work. But I see how your code does work. Noted for the future :P